# I need to update the state of a radio button group with the label?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

The below is from my Child Element (Step 2):

```
<input class="radioInput" type="radio" name="sex" value="male"
 onChange{(e) => props.setFormData({...props.formData, sex: e.target.value})}>
</input>
<label class="radioLabel" value="male" for="male"> Male </label>

<input class="radioInput" type="radio" name="sex" value="female"
 onChange{(e) => props.setFormData({...props.formData, sex: e.target.value})}>
</input>
<label class="radioLabel" value="female" for="female"> Female </label>
```

This is the Parent Element:

```
const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
 firstName: '',
 lastName: '',
 sex: 'male',
})
```

This is my CSS:

```
.radioInput[type="radio"] {
    display: inline-flex;
    overflow: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    position: fixed;
}

.radioInput[type="radio"]:checked + label {
    background-color: rgb(253 224 71);
    border: 1px solid transparent;
}

.radioLabel {
    color:rgb(17 24 39);
    border: 1px solid rgb(209 213 219);
    border-radius: 0.375rem;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 8px 14px;
    font-size: 14px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: background 0.1s;
}

.radioLabel:hover {
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    background-color: rgb(253 224 71);
}
```

Now when I allow the radio buttons to show the circle boxes to check, this works. However I want the styling to be as I've shown, but I'm struggling getting the buttons to change the state ...

Comment: React uses `className` not `class` in JSX: `className="radioInput"` for example.

Comment: The `for` attribute should match the `id` of the `input`. [Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/for)

Comment: Thank you both, the `for` attribute did fix the issue! I have also replaced the `class` for `className` too!